# How to remotely connect to another windows machine in the network and get the OS information from that machine? (other than Telnet)

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module

I have been assigned to write a Perl script wherein I will have to connect to another windows machine on the network and then get that machine's OS name and version.

I have achieved this successfully using Perl's [NET::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Telnet) module. But as Telnet is not installed on Windows by default, it will be a prerequisite for running my script and my TL does not want that.

Could anybody please suggest me some way to do this using something which is a part of Windows default installation like rpc. Also it will be great if the suggested approach can also work for unix, MAC or HP machines.

Comment: [http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod](go through this links)

Comment: Too me, this seem like a windows question as much as a perl question, you should tag it with windows as well. Also, did you try to search for something like "[windows] +information +remotly" ?

Comment: I have tried to search a lot...but I did not try a google search exactly like this....I will try it....Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Getting configuration information remotely on Windows systems is typically done by querying [WMI data (Windows Management Instrumentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can also do this from Perl. Please see a module such as [Win32::Process::Info::WMI](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aProcess%3a%3aInfo%3a%3aWMI).

Comment: I tried the code given in the link Win32::Process::Info::WMI provided by you. But I am getting error as below:

Error - Variant 'WMI' is unsupported on your configuration. Disallowed on load of Win32::Process::Info. at wmi_module.pl line 2
 at wmi_module.pl line 2
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at wmi_module.pl line 2.

Could you please help me resolve this error?

Comment: This code worked in my personal laptop, but its not working in my office pc.....also this code gives output in terms of hashes....How can I get the output understandable by a lay man?